# Security Trimmed Control Show Only to Authenticated Users

Tags: 2010, security-trimming

I have a public facing website and on the homepage there are few contents that I want to show only to Authenticated Users.. Anonymous users should not be able to see it, what Permissions String should I use?

I guess ViewPages and ViewListItems will do? But can someone confirm please..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  set `AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly"` Example:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly">
....
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Reference: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/hide-elements-in-sharepoint-for-anonymous-users-using

Comment: Sounds perfect, thanks.. Let me try, and I will close once done..