# SharePoint Library Name shows to user without having permisson

Tags: permissions

1. I created the document library and broke the permission from the site level. Then granted the access to particular person.
2. By default, the site is accessible to Everyone (authenticated users).
3. The another user can see the library name from Site Content of Setting  without having the permission to the library which I created in no.1
4. Normally user might not see the library or list from Site Content who does not have access to those libraries and lists.
5. I surprise, this is effecting to the new library that I created.
6. Previous created library was fine and could not see by the user who did not have access to those library.

Anyone has the same issue as I mention above.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you check that user having Read Only permission?

Comment: Hi DOM, The user have no permission at all to that library. That's why I surprised that the user can see the library which is supposed not to be.

Comment: Is user is site collection admin or is there additional permission assign in document library?

Comment: The user is not in the site collection admin group and the user has read only access to the site level. The library had broken the inheritance permission from the site level and granted to other few users. (The user cannot see any contents in the library but my concern is why the user can see the library name from the Site Content. This is not supposed to be).

Comment: Check the site permissions for the user though having Limited access, and read only pemissions user can see all the content on the back end

Comment: did you find any solution to this? We are experiencing this same behavior in a customer's environment. We added some libraries with individual permissions and they show up in every user's Site Content and navigation. Those users cannot see any content of the libraries, but simply being able to see them is not welcome.
This only affects some librariess and, additionally the behavior is not consistent about all users. Additionally: I cannot see any users with "`Limited Access`" in the site permissions. Any further ideas appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the similar issues .. I am trying to share a site and task approval to items in list for users ( external suppliers ) but I cannot fully secure suppliers being able to browse user informations... my findings : user with restricted read access cannot access to the SharePoint
user with read access can access to sharepoint but has also been granted with the 'browse user information ' , as such he can check the shared with and email everybody....
user with restricted read on list with a broken inherence but with assigned approval task ( OOB approval workflow to a list item get also gra

Answer (score 1):

The user might have limited access permission level. Did you check user permission by using the check permission ribbon button in the library?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the same scenario, even I am getting the same. The user who has Read permission in the Site and no permission in the list will able to see the list in Site Contents page, but will not be able to access the list.

But this is not the same when you deal with item level permission. If unique permission is set for an item in a library, user who has access to the item will be able to see the item in the library.

This is the default behavior of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check the site permissions for the user though having Limited access, and read only pemissions user can see all the content on the back end. Use SPSecurityTrimmed control instead to view the content to the specific group. Or to hide the content from specific user group.

Check the following links for that,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa6a7c32-c530-48d0-a73f-aa4d7b1e2cb2/remove-access-to-site-settings-from-cog-menu?forum=sharepointadmin

[Security Trimmed Control Show Only to Authenticated Users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96596/security-trimmed-control-show-only-to-authenticated-users)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/security-trimmed-control-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/03/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint/